# Using SendKeys to maximize browser window

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

How to use **Sendkeys.Send()** to maximize a browser window?
I tried with `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("%  (x)")` but it works like **Ctrl+Space**,not as **Ctrl+Space+X**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you put `x`in brackets? `"% x"` should work.

Comment: no,it doesn't works.It works like Ctrl+Space and x is printed on focus textbox.

Comment: Try sending `"% "` then `"x"` separately? Two method calls, I mean.

Comment: You could also try this: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/hiding-windows-c-sharp-t973/

Comment: I think your 2nd link could work.But i use pr.ProcessName == "internet explorer" which doesn't work.Could you tell what would be the process name for IE?

Comment: Sure, I think it's just `iexplore.exe`

Comment: this works,but at the same time it hangs IE.Works good for notepad like as example,but not for IE.Even i use separately "% " and "x" but also it works as Ctrl+Space !!